# How can I use a static helper function(javascript) in SCSS to set the base url for images for different environments?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

In my SCSS file I need to use different base urls for different app environments which will be prepended to the image name.

**Example:**

- For production environment

`background: url(/prod/image.png);`

- For development environment

`background: url(/dev/image.png);`

The helper function which I'm using in the rest of my app returns the base path of the static assets and it looks like this:

```
static imagePath() {
  let imagesPath;

  if (this.isProduction()) {
    basePath = '/prod';
  } else {
    basePath = '/dev';
   }
   return basePath
  }
```

How to achieve this?

**Edit:***

I'm using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` which won't let me output multiple `css` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can have 2 main files (`dev.scss` and `prod.scss`) that will look like:

```
// prod.scss

$basePath: '/prod';
@import "style.scss";
```

and same for `dev.scss`.

Otherwise you can use some placeholder for path prefix and substitute it with actual prefix on post-processing step. For example you can use [this](https://github.com/gridonic/postcss-replace) plugin for PostCSS.

**UPDATE:**
Following discussion in comments here is (untested) example of how webpack configuration may look like:

```
module.exports = {
    // ....
    module: {
        rules: [
            // ....
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: {
                    loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
                        replacements: [
                            {
                                pattern: /{urlPrefix}/ig,
                                replacement: () => process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? '/dev' : '/prod',
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 'sass-loader'),
                }
            },
            // ....
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new StringReplacePlugin(),
        // ....
    ],
    // ....
};
```

Comment: I can't create two separate stylesheets as I'm using ```extract-text-webpack-plugin``` and I can't get it to output multiple ```css``` files.

Comment: Then second approach (with post-processing) may suit your needs better

Comment: You may use [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin) for string replacement. So you can use something like `$basePath: '{urlPrefix}';` and then use string replacement plugin to replace `{urlPrefix}` with actual url prefix.

Comment: It'd be great if you can post a little "How to" for this. I can't seem to figure out anything from the plugin docs.

Comment: Had to change a couple of things here and there and got it to work. Can't thank you enough :)